# Does "yarn install" ignore what's in node_modules already?

Tags: yarnpkg

When I run `yarn install` (or just `yarn` for short) and I don't have a `yarn.lock` file yet, will the result depend on what packages are *already* installed in my `node_modules` directory? Or will `node_modules` end up in the same state regardless of what's already in there?

In other words, do I need to run `rm -rf node_modules` "just in case" before running `yarn`, to make sure that I get the latest versions?

Answer (score 0):

yarn seems to wipe node_modules, generate a lockfile, then download everything without lockfile for me (0.18.1).

If I then modify node_modules, further yarn calls don't do anything, but adding a dependency introducing a change to the lockfile then calls it to wipe my node_modules again.

(I recall reading a yarn github thread about how wiping node_modules for any lockfile changes being the normal behavior, but now I don't know how to find that comment)